# How to play iTunes music from from a script run from the terminal or AIML pattern?

Tags: terminal, python, itunes, applescript, bots

I want to write a command that launches iTunes and play the first song that is in the playlist or song list. I can launch iTunes from my code but it doesn't start the song automatically.

My AIML (Artificial Intelligence Modelling Language) pattern is here

```
 <category>
      <pattern> PLAY MUSIC FROM MY COMPUTER </pattern>
      <template>
           <random>
             <li>Sure thing! </li>
             <li>OKAY,  </li>
             <li>OK! </li>
          </random>
          <system>open -a /Applications/itunes.app/Contents/MacOS/itunes/play</system>
      </template>
  </category>
```

Comment: Have you [looked at this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20011108211802830)?

Answer (score 0):

This Terminal command (for example), would use the following AppleScript code (in Terminal) to play the first song from playlist "Pink Floyd" in iTunes.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to tell its playlist "Pink Floyd" to play track 1'
```

Comment: Just an FYI... The first Playlist I have created in iTune is named Pink Floyd and your AppleScript code, as coded, did not play its first track. It actually played the first track in the first album of the Library. Using `osascript -e 'tell application "iTunes" to get name of every playlist'` gave me the names of every Playlist in their numerical order position. Also interesting is that when I replaced the `playlist 1` with `playlist "Pink Floyd"` and it finished playing the first track in that playlist, it then played a completely random song not in that Playlist.

Comment: BTW The first seven playlists were Library, Music, Movies, TV Shows, Podcasts, Audiobooks, Genius, which are a default part of iTunes and none of which were user created and then my first Playlist Pink Floyd. This may vary depending on the version of iTunes being used.

Comment: `tell application "iTunes" to play the first track of (the first user playlist where special kind = none and smart = false)`